# Proof check: If AB = I, then prove BA = I WITHOUT using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove that, for linear functions on $ℝ^n$, $AB = I$, then $BA = I$.

Note: I do ***NOT*** want a proof using matrices (I already figured that out, very simple).

---

My attempt to prove this:

We know that $AB = I$, so I would put this in the usual function notation: $A(B(x)) = I(x) = x$. Then this would imply that $A(x)$ is the inverse of $B$.

Now because these are linear transormations and the inverse of $B$ exists, that implies these functions are onto and one-to-one (proof given elsewhere). This means that the following should be well defined: $B(A(x))$. We also know that the inverse of $B$ is $A$, so:

$$A(I(x)) = A(x) = I(A(x)) = A(B(A(x)))$$

(because $A(B(y)) = I(y)$)

So then we see that $B(A(x)) = I(x)$. That is, $BA = I$.

---

Is this correct or is this "proof" flawed? This is my first linear algebra proof, so I hope I didn't do too bad! (I'm on an analysis track)

Comment: But you have used matrices $A$, $B$ (or their linear transformations, which is the same). And $A(x)$ is not the inverse of $B$, as $A(x)$ is not a map.

Comment: Could you expand on "then we see"? How do you get from $A(I(x))=A(B(A(x)))$ to $B(A(x))=I(x)$? Also, where do you use the assumption that the functions are linear?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since the question is about linear transformations, it would be very difficult to answer it without using linear transformations.  I suspect that, at the level of this question, linear transformations are not to be considered the same as matrices.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Then perhaps that is the key, to identify both, if the "proof with matrices is very simple", as the OP says.

Comment: I took the argument of A on both ends of the equality. I(x) = B(A(x)). Because it is one-to-one and onto, I can do that, correct? I was hoping I got the basics, but now I worry I am not understanding this.

Comment: I need to look at my matrix proof again, I will be back in about an hour. Sorry for that… Maybe should have waited. Thank you all for your time and help so far.

Comment: I think you are on the right way. It depends what you kind of results you already assume.

Comment: The subtlety of this problem is that it fails in the infinite-dimensional case. The essential statement is that if $B$ is one-to-one, then it is also onto (or alternatively if $A$ is onto, then it is also one-to-one). These statements fail in infinite dimensional case. Once you know how to get these statements (I suspect you are allowed to use them) then indeed you can go along the lines of: $AB=I$ implies $BAB=B$, so you have $BAB(v)=B(v)$ for any $v$. Since $B$ is onto, any $x\in \mathbb R^n$ can be written as $B(v)$, which means that $BAx=x$ for all $x$, i.e. $BA=I$.

Answer (score 3):

The given proof is incorrect logically. You need a result that B is surjective if AB = I.

Since B is surjecive, for each $y \in R^n$, there exists $x \in R^n$ such that $ y = Bx$,

$$BAy = BA(Bx) = B(ABx) = BIx = Bx = y$$
so BA = I.

prove B is surjective is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

A general result about `sets` is that, if the composition $AB$ of two maps is injective, then $B$ is injective. If $AB$ is surjective, the $A$ is surjective.

Now for a *linear map* between finite dimensional spaces, with the *same dimension*, it is equivalent to say it is injective, surjective or bijective. This is because of the *rank-nummity theorem*.

So we conclude $A$ and $B$ are isomorphisms, inverse of each other. In particular, $BA=I$.